# Stuck on a deductive proof

Tags: proof-verification

```
Premises    (p → t) ∨ q
             r → s
            (p ∨ q) → r
 Conclusion s
```

Very new to deductive proofs, I have the 3 above premises and a conclusion. I am confused as to why the answer is not just one line stating that `(p ∨ q) → r`is equal to `s` using `r → s, believe the rule is called the law of equivalence

Comment: The conclusion does not follow from the premises.

Comment: What do you mean? As in my premises are incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Notice in your premises, the only way to conclude $s$ is to prove that $r$ is true, and that is only possible if $p \vee q$ is true. Is it possible to derive this from your first statement?

Comment: I had a feeling the first premise was incorrect, if is was `(t → p) ∨ q` then I would be able to conclude s, correct?

Comment: @PeterWilson yes, you are right

Comment: I have completed it there, thank you very much!